# Looking for a way to reverse pan/tilt orientation back to x, y

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

I have something like follows:
Input x, y and h to get pan and tilt orientation

```
        double dz = Math.sqrt( x*x + y*y );
        double rotPan = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(x / y));
        double rotTilt = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan( h / dz ));
```

Is it possible to reverse the effect of Math only with **h** given to starting point and reach the initial **x** and **y** values?

Comment: Aside from your question: use [`Math.hypot(x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-) instead of `Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)`, and [`Math.atan2(x, y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#atan2-double-double-) instead of `Math.atan(x / y)` (same for the other atan).

Comment: Thx, I changed those. Still interested for reverse to x/y :-)

Comment: It's just rearranging the equations. Do it on paper, it will be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
double x = dz * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(rotPan)); 
double y = dz * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(rotPan));
```

Unfortunately, it is not possible to restore the initial values completely.

For example, x = 2 and y = 5 will give you exactly the same dz, rotPan (and rotTilt, which is not needed), as x = -2 and y = -5. So the best you can do is to restore (x, y) with a possible change of sign for both coordinates. Btw, you could avoid this problem, if you use atan2 function instead of atan:

```java
double dz = Math.hypot(x, y);
double rotPan = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(x, y));
double rotTilt = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(h, dz));
```

If you use the above formulas to calculate rotPan and rotTilt, then the formulas at the top of my post will always give you the initial coordinates (with the limits of the numerical errors).

Comment: Yes now it works, Thank you. Have to change cos for x and sin for y but now it works as a charmed. Its easy if you know how ;-)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to rearrange the equations.

```
        double dz = Math.sqrt( x*x + y*y );
        double rotPan = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan(x / y));
        double rotTilt = Math.toDegrees(Math.atan( h / dz ));
```

Given `rotTilt`, you can calculate the ratio of `h` to `dz`:

```
double hOverDz = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(rotTilt));
```

So if you know `h`, you can calculate `dz`:

```
dz = h / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(rotTilt));
```

Given `rotPan`, you can calculate the ratio of `x` to `y`:

```
double xOverY = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(rotPan));
```

so:

```
x = y * xOverY;
```

Subtituting in and rearranging:

```
dz = sqrt(y^2 * xOverY^2 + y*y)
   = sqrt((xOverY^2 + 1) * y*y)
dz = y * sqrt(1 + xOverY^2) 

y  = dz / sqrt(1 + xOverY^2)
   = h / (tan(rotTilt) * sqrt(1 + xOverY^2))

y  = h / tan(rotTile) * sqrt(1 + tan(rotPan)^2))
```

hence

```
x  = y * xOverY
   = (h / tan(rotTile) * sqrt(1 + tan(rotPan)^2))) * tan(rotPan)
```

Comment: It was not easy to  understand it, because I am not e mathematician, but I think I have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After input from Andy Turner and clearing what it exactly means, I got:

```
    double dz = h / Math.tan(Math.toRadians(rotTilt));
    double xOverY = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(rotPan));
    double x = Math.round(dz / Math.sqrt(1 + xOverY*xOverY));
    double y = Math.round(x * xOverY);

    if (pan > 90 || pan < 0) { x *=-1; y *=-1; }    // sign correction if angel > 90 or < 0
```

I don't know, if there is another way because of wrong result if angel > 90 or < 0 (it occurs, if negative value (x or y) in my example).

EDIT:
Ok, its not working. If i put **rotPan** = **90** and rotTilt = *any*, dx and dy are always **0**

I don't understand your way of solution or something is wrong.

Comment: If rotTilt = 90 it means that arctan of h/dz is 90 degrees, but it means that h/dz is positive infinity. So it's not surprising that this implies dz = 0, so both dx and dy are zeros. In other words you can't obtain rotTilt = 90 for any non-zero dx and dy (well, unless h is a positive infinity....)

Comment: My mistake: I mean rotPan not rotTilt.